# SCORM lib for php

Tags: php, scorm

we have developed e-learning web site for one of our customer.
recently he asked he need SCORM feed.
i dornt know whether my system is compatible with scrom.
do any body know any opensource php tool or lib to generate scrom from existing data.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to determine is whether your site would be considered a learning management system or a piece of content. The SCORM implementation varies considerably based of what you are trying to develop. Check out http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/ for a good explanation of SCORM and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Chamilo 1.9.6 and works well with SCORM 1.2 and 2004. This was used as evaluation tool (test) with up to 90 questions.

Answer (score 0):

- Have a look at Moodle project - SCORM module: http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/SCORM_module It's open source, but I do not know, it the SCORM related code is easy to use outside Moodle.
- [www.dokeos.com](http://www.dokeos.com) comes with open source edition containing SCORM module.
- Or try [Chamilo](http://www.chamilo.org), it is maybe better fork of dokeos.
- [Drupal has a limited support for SCORM](http://drupal.org/project/scorm), too.
- Good reputation has [eFront](http://www.efrontlearning.net).
- [Ilias](http://www.ilias.de) is certified for SCORM 2004.
- [TinyLMS](http://www.randelshofer.ch/tinylms/) is interesting project - JavaScript only.

Answer (score 0):

Also get idea from http://www.vsscorm.net/run-time-environment-rte/run-time-environment-downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget Chamilo!! http://www.chamilo.org
You can try a demo at http://campus.chamilo.org
Chamilo supports SCORM is also a claroline/dokeos fork

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but this doesn't answer OP's question. Chamilo seems to be an amazing tool, but the OP wants a lib for the LMS he is developing. He is not asking for an LMS product.

Comment: You should also comment all the answers below then, all of them mention Chamilo. Because Chamilo is an open source proyect, the code is available in github, so he can be "inspired" by the PHP code.