# Implement scorm on symfony platform

Tags: symfony, scorm1.2

I have developed an e-learning platform using Symfony2 and I will like integrate it with Scorm 1.2, but I didn't find any information about Symfony2-Scorm integration, anybody can help me?

Comment: Therre is a composer package for PHP and SCORM, https://github.com/claroline/ScormBundle with it you can try to adapt it to Symfony2.

Comment: I saw that bundle, but it's difficult to adapt without any documentation.

Comment: Duplicate by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498452/scorm-lib-for-php)